# C# UWP Pages unable to see UserControls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, azure-devops

I believe the project metadata itself is somehow broken. I can make new pages, and new user controls. I can add them in XAML, as shown below (most of the generated code left out for brevity). **This compiles:**

```
<Page
    x:Class="MyApp.Pages.MyPage"
    …
    xmlns:myControls="using:MyApp.Models">

    <Grid>
        <myControls:MyControl Name="MyControlName"></myControls:MyControl>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And on the backend:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And then the UserControl:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="MyApp.Models.MyControl"
    …>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And on the backend for that:

```
public sealed partial class MyControl : UserControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As soon as I try and add a reference to that user control in the C# file of the page such as:

```
public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.MyControlName.Width = 10; // This line breaks it.
    }
}
```

I get a compiler error, stating that " 'MyPage' does not contain a definition for 'MyControlName' and no extension method..."

This is true for any arbitrarily named user control I make, in any arbitrary location within the project, and any arbitrarily named page I make, likewise in any arbitrary location in the project. The project itself seems to no longer have the ability to enable a page's CS file to "see" a user control placed on a page. Other non-user controls (such as a `TextBox`) still work fine, however.

I know the references are all correct, because the project compiles and runs when that one line is removed from the C# file. The XAML side alone compiles. Also, note that this error persists regardless of what property or method of the control I am accessing, or even when I am setting the control to a new value (like `this.MyControlName = new MyControl();`). The page simply cannot find that definition for the control of that name in the C# file, even though the XAML-side can find that control's definition. The control's UI even displays properly on the page in design view.

If I try to work around the issue, such as explicitly declaring `MyControl MyControlName { get; set; }` on the MyPage.cs file, it builds and runs (even though it shouldn't, because that is a duplicate declaration of that name for a property on the `MyPage` class). Trying to interact with the UI elsewhere in the app, however, results in errors being throw along the lines of:

"`this.<Project>k__BackingField was null`"

My research has suggested this is an error normally associated with serialization. I am not ever explicitly using serialization. I imagine that serialization is used in the process of generating the `xxx.g.i.cs` files from the XAML, so perhaps it is an error in the project relating to how it governs generating those files?

The actual project is version-controlled using Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS). Rolling back to a changeset prior to this issue occurring (a changeset that compiled and ran fine) does not solve the problem.

I have gone so far as to use Visual Studio on a different PC, mapping the project (which has never been on that PC before), and getting a previous version prior to the issues. The problem still persists.

It seems as if the project itself and/or its metadata or generated files may have somehow been damaged, deleted, or corrupted. Somehow, this damage seems to extend back now to changesets in VSTS that were checked in and completely functional prior to this issue occurring.

The only last thing to note, is that my PC did crash (as in needing hard reset) while I had the project open in Visual Studio, and some of the files in the project (.cs and .xaml) were open at the time. I could see how this might corrupt files, but I do not see how this seems to have retroactively damaged the fully functional changesets prior to the crash.

This project consists of several months of development, and an extensive history on VSTS. It is completely unusable (since the core functionalities of the app all rely on user controls). The only solution I can think of is to create another project in the solution, and copy and paste the code from the files into new files in that project. I would still like, however, to fix the existing project if possible, so that the hundreds of previous changesets are usable still. Any ideas on how to fix this (or even where to begin looking for an issue) would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, that seems strange. About the mapping on another computer: try this if you haven't already tried: Create a new solution with new name, copy only the .cs and .xaml.cs files (I mean, exclude any configuration file connected with the corrupted solution). Most probably while direct cloning from VSTS, some configuration files was also cloned that were previously corrupted.

Comment: How about the ignored files (i.e. .gitignore) in your project repo, could one of them be causing the problem?

Comment: I worked it out. Apparently this was two issues at once. Once issue was the .cs file not seeing the UserControl. By changing `Name` to `x:Name` in the XAML declaration, it worked (I uncovered this while trying out suggestion, @Muzib. As for the other "BackingField" issue... I repaired my installation of Visual Studio, and the issue vanished. Dont know what was up, but VERY happy it appears to be working again! Thank you for the suggestions!